# What is a better logic for making an IF condition condition better?

Tags: logic

I have two values which occur randomly and I need to write a condition to set a boolean value.

```
if(a == 1 && b == 1) then set both true
if(a == 1 && b == 0) then a as true and b as false
if(a == 0 && b == 1) then b as true and a as false
if(a == 0 && b == 0) then set both false
```

this conditions works fine
my question here is do we have better approach/logic for the same?

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: There's really nothing you need to do. If you have to later use: `if (a) // do something`, it really doesn't matter if you precede it by the statement `a=(a==1)` or not.

Answer (score 3):

That's as simple as assigning directly the boolean test:

```
a = (a==1)
b = (b==1)
```

Comment: We cant assign assignment operator to condition? this again result in the same conditional loop which is there earlier

Comment: You don't need the condition.

Comment: null isn't equal anything but null. So if a is null the test null == 1 wil return false